# Implicit declaration of function 'UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want save image to camera roll in apple Watch

this is my code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"w0-1.jpg"];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

can you help me please??

Comment: might be helpful conversation https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4948

Answer (score -2):

You cannot save image to saved photo album. You can only save image to your application folder.

Comment: How to? with uiimagejpegrepresentation ?